# Can I access rails app resources from Rails Engine or Mountable Engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a gem that is Rails Engine (or Mountable Engine).
And it wants to list resouces from parent rails app.

For example:

```
# one rails app on routes
mount MyGem::Engine, at: '/my_gem' if Rails.env.development?
```

And when I access `/my_gem`, I want to list files from `app/views/foo/xxxx`, `app/assets/my_gem/xxxx` etc (not my gem views, assets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gem you can use: `Rails.application.root` to get the root folder of the main app, from there you can proceed.